# Usage of | and :== in Java doc

Tags: java, regex, solr, lucene

I am trying to understand the regular expression in Solr and came across [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html) Java doc where explains "Regular expressions are built from the following abstract syntax".

I am trying to follow each functionality and run a quick test but having a hard time understanding what it really means.

1. In the Java doc, they have used a lot of symbols including `|` and `:==`, what does that mean? Is that some sort of convention in Java or Java doc specifically?
2. Looks like there are four "columns" there, is the first column like top category and the second columns are all the options under that category.

Comment: [BNF grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Comment: @Amadan, that totally makes sense, however, if you look at the first appearance of pipe, `regexp::=unionexp|`, there was not even an operand after the pipe, should I understand "regexp is defined as unionexp" only or i should actually go one extra line "regexp is defined as unionexp or unionexp is define...", or it is just a typo that they should really remove the pipe.

Comment: I'd agree with @arcy that going over the formal grammar is the hard way to get at the regex syntax.  I would swear I've seen a similar document from Lucene directly, but the [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax) explains how the syntax departs from the more familiar Perl syntax quite well.

Answer (score 2):

These are symbols in a formal grammar; `:==` indicates a production from a symbol, and `|` indicates a logical "or". The basic idea is that `a :== b` is a rule indicating that something represented by 'a' can be produced by choosing this rule, producing 'b'. It sounds less than useful until you have studied something about what the grammars are for.

The 'or' allows one rule to handle two productions, so that `a :== b | c` indicates that 'a' can produce either 'b' or 'c'.

It seems rather the long way 'round to figure out how regular expressions work starting from a formal grammar if you aren't already familiar with them. I'd look for another explanation.